# Calender Events Management

Tags: android, calendar

I want to ask a about a problem regarding Creation of the `Events` via `Calender`(Native) in `Android`

Here is the scenario :-

With the help of my application I am opening the Default Calender of Android to create a Calender Event. But here I am stuck in a  problem - **HOW TO DIFFERENTIATE BETWEEN MY APP CREATED EVENTS OR THE REST OF THE EVENTS (created by default Android App)**

I have currently no code to share upon. A good or relevant link is needed.Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no direct methods of accessing it but, using the [`CalendarContract class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html) which you can invoke using the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//calendarEventID is unique ID returned stored in the contentprovider.
intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events/" + String.valueOf(calendarEventID)));
startActivity(intent);
```

To get the unique _id of the events that match your requirement you can save it on your app using SQLITE Database.

1. [BaseColumns Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID)
2. [CalendarContract Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html)